# Error in TextInputLayout is not cleared after text change

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

In the `EditText` widget, after calling `setError("Error")` and, then, typing text into the field, the error is being cleared.
In `TextInputLayout` is not - the error stays visible even if the input changes. I know, it is possible to reset it manually by calling `setError(null)`, but is there any way (maybe XML flag) to turn on automatic error clearing?

Comment: You'll need `TextChangeListener` on **EditText** to do so, i don't think there's any other way.

Comment: No, there is no way to turn on automatic error clearing. TextWatcher class listens for text changes while typing.